# Best way to extract a timezone from a mail Date header in Java?

Tags: java, timezone, jakarta-mail

I need to store the timezone an email was sent from. Which is the best way to extract it from the email's 'Date:' header (an RFC822 date)? And what is the recommended format to store it in the database (I'm using hibernate)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to parse with JodaTime as it supports ISO8601 see [Date and Time Parsing and Formatting in Java with Joda Time](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/date-time-parsing-formatting-joda-time.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter parser2 = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
System.out.println(parser2.parseDateTime(your_date_string));
```

Times must always be stored in UTC (GMT) with a timezone - i.e. after parsing convert from the timezone to GMT and remove daylight savings offset and save the original timezone.

You must store the date with the timezone after converting to UTC.

If you remove or don't handle the timezone it will cause problems when dealing with data that has come from a different timezone.

Comment: **Wrong!** Its far better to store the DateTime *with* the timezone so long as it is correct and your using a modern datetime library like Joda. That is handle the TimeZone. By throwing away timezone and normalizing to UTC your loosing data that could be valuable to the user particularly if its a mobile/global application. **Also SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe!** ... I'm tempted to -1 you.

Comment: @AdamGent That's what I meant by "if you remove or don't handle the timezone it can cause problems....". I'll edit to make this crystal clear.

Comment: Please Remove the blog post too or atl east note the serious concurrency danger of making a public static array of simpledateformat.

Comment: I've removed the use of SimpleDateFormat to use JodaTime, even though did consider the one built into JAXB

Comment: Thanks (sorry for sounding demanding)! Also I had no idea JAXB had time formatting/parsing. What are the JAXB classes that do that? Also ISO8601 is not compatible with RFC822 format. ISO is superior format but unfortunately emails uses the RFC822 format.

Comment: @AdamGent javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(...). Also I have no problem from me with your comments - it's been helpful and improved the quality...

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend you use [Mime4J](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/).**

The library is designed for parsing all kinds of email crap.
For parsing dates you would use its [DateTimeParser](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/field/datetime/parser/DateTimeParser.html).

```
int zone = new DateTimeParser(new StringReader("Fri, 27 Jul 2012 09:13:15 -0400")).zone();
```

After that I usually convert the datetimes to **[Joda's DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)**. Don't use SimpleDateFormatter as will not cover all the cases for RFC822.

Below will get you the **Joda TimeZone** (from the int zone above) which is superior to Java's TZ.

```
// Stupid hack in case the zone is not in [-+]zzzz format
final int hours;
final int minutes;
if (zone > 24 || zone < -24 ) {
    hours = zone / 100;
    minutes = minutes = Math.abs(zone % 100);
}
else {
    hours = zone;
    minutes = 0;
}
DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(hours, minutes);
```

Now the only issue is that the Time Zone you will get always be a numeric time zone which may still not be the correct time zone of the user sending the email (assuming the mail app sent the users TZ and not just UTC).

For example -0400 is not EDT (ie America/New_York) because it does not take Daylight savings into account.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the data from the header using some sort of substring or regular expression. Parse the date with a SimpleDateFormatter to create a Date object.

Comment: Thanks jhawk28. However I can get the Date using the MailDateFormat class. That class also parses the timezone, but there seems to be no easy way to find that TimeZone, except for copying code from  MailDateParser.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone in the email will not show in which timezone it was send. Some programs use ever UTC or GMT. Of course the time zone is part of the date time value and must also be parse.

Why do you want know it. 
  - Do you want normalize the timestamp? Then use a DateFormat for parsing it.
  - Do you want detect the timezome of the user that send the email? This will not correctly work.

Comment: I want to detect the timezone of the user that sent the email. Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Because some programs send ever UTC or GMT time independent of the timezone of the user. It is the timezone of the formated Date String and not of the user computer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already mentioned this in one of your comments, but I think it's your best answer.  The JavaMail library contains RFC822 Date header parsing code in `javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat`.  Unfortunately it doesn't expose the TimeZone parsing directly, so you will need to copy the necessary code directly from `javax.mail.internet.MailDateParser`, but it's worth taking advantage of the careful work already done.

As for storing it, the parser will give you the date as an offset, so you should be able to store it just fine as an `int` (letting Hibernate translate that to your database for you).

Comment: He can use the Mime4J DateTime parser instead of the friendly scoped (ironic) MailDateParser. See my answer.